# How do I use an ICU collation as my default in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm developing a Rails / Postgres app. I develop on a Mac. Others use Linux. Production is on Heroku.

Collations are broken on the Mac, so I get slightly different sorting than Linux and Heroku. This causes tests involving sorting to occasionally fail or act inconsistently. The work around is to use ICU collations to get consistent sorting, but I can't figure out how to make that the default.

[Postgres will not create a database with an ICU collation](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Collations). If I set the collation to be `en-US-x-icu` in database.yml...

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  host: <%= ENV['DB_HOST'] || 'localhost' %>
  username: <%= ENV['DB_USER'] || 'postgres' %>
  password: <%= ENV['DB_PASSWORD'] || '' %>
  collation: en-US-x-icu
```

I get an error, `invalid locale name: "en-US-x-icu"`, despite that appearing in `pg_collation`.

```
$ rails db:migrate:reset
Dropped database 'email_integrator_development'
Dropped database 'email_integrator_test'
PG::WrongObjectType: ERROR:  invalid locale name: "en-US-x-icu"
Couldn't create 'email_integrator_development' database. Please check your configuration.
rails aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::WrongObjectType: ERROR:  invalid locale name: "en-US-x-icu"
```

Perhaps there is a way to get Rails to set the collaction per connection or per table?

I'm using Rails 6 and Postgres 11, but I can move to Postgres 12 if necessary.

Comment: I am afreaid that you will have to add the collation to each string column definition.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I was afraid of that. I wonder if I can fix the collations on my Mac instead. If you post that as an answer, I'll accept it. Thank you. Do you know if there's ICU improvements coming in Postgres 13?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid that you will have to add the collation to each string column definition.

Currently, you cannot use ICU collations as database default. [There have been efforts to improve that](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/5e756dd6-0e91-d778-96fd-b1bcb06c161a%402ndquadrant.com), but nothing committable has come of it yet.

But it is easy to fix your database afterwards. Using `psql`, you can run

```
SELECT format(
          'ALTER TABLE %I.%I ALTER %I TYPE %I%s;',
          table_schema,
          table_name,
          column_name,
          data_type,
          '(' || character_maximum_length || ')'
       )
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE data_type IN ('character', 'character varying', 'text')
  AND table_schema NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema', 'pg_toast') \gexec
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and the script. I assume that's going to rebuild indexes?

Answer (score 0):

You can monkey-patch ActiveRecord:

```ruby
module ActiveRecord
  module ConnectionAdapters
    module PostgreSQL
      module ColumnMethods
        def new_column_definition(name, type, **options) # :nodoc:
          if integer_like_primary_key?(type, options)
            type = integer_like_primary_key_type(type, options)
          end
          type = aliased_types(type.to_s, type)
          options[:primary_key] ||= type == :primary_key
          options[:null] = false if options[:primary_key]
          # set default collation for a column if not set explicitly
          options[:collation] = "en-US-x-icu" if options[:collation].blank? && (type == :string || type == :text)
          create_column_definition(name, type, options)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```